# Unable to display API response

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

My API is getting a JSON response. Now, I'm trying to just display it however possible in one of my components just to understand and observe how the data is being transferred and displayed, so I can build over it later.

For some reason, I cannot get anything to show, even though my component is working (I keep some other stuff in it to keep track of it showing or not).

Any suggestion what am I doing wrong or how to try to get it working? I've run out of ideas and my internet search has been highly unfruitful.

contact.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/Http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from "rxjs/operator/map";
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { IContact } from './icontact';
import './rxjs-operators';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getContacts(): Observable<IContact[]> {
        return this.http.get(API_URL)
            .map(response => <IContact[]>response.json());
    }
}
```

contact.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contact.service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/Http';
import { IContact } from '../icontact';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact',
    templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
    providers: [ContactService]
})

export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    private contactlist: IContact[];

    constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
            (contacts) => { this.contactlist = contacts; },
            (error) => { console.log(error); }
        );
  }
}
```

contact.component.html - if I get it right, below template should be able to display stuff from my API but it comes back empty.

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
{{contact}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component doesn't have a field called `contacts`, so your `ngFor` will never have anything to loop over.

Try changing it to

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contactList">
{{contact}}
</div>
```

Comment: Close - but not exactly. Something I didn't see myself - contactlist not contactList ;-) i was trying contactList previously and it didn't work and I thought I'm doing something wrong, turned out it was a typo. Silly me. Thanks!